# C# VSTO Worksheet Unique Identifier or referencing best practices

Tags: c#, vsto

I'm developing a VSTO addin that needs to persist cell references down on specific worksheets in a workbook. What is the best recommended way to do this? At the moment, I'm just persisting the worksheet name down but this can obviously be renamed by the user so this isn't an option. Is there a way to somehow store a reference to a cell on a worksheet such that if the sheet is renamed then the reference will automatically point to the renamed worksheet?

Thanks

Comment: actually, I might have just found the answer for this. There's a CustomProperties object on the Worksheet object that I can use to store a one time generated unique identifier for the worksheet (eg. guid) that I can use to track what objects point to which worksheets. I'll give this a try and see if it solves my problem!

Comment: I'm a Word, not Excel person, but I believe every worksheet (as well as the workbook) has a CodeName property that is immutable. When the user changes the worksheet name it does NOT change the CodeName. I think the Excel folks use that.

Comment: @CindyMeister this CodeName is only available if the VBProject window is open though, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

Using CustomProperties on the Worksheet object solved my problem. I just assign a GUID to each worksheet